# Loop an Array for Dynamic Scoped Slots

Tags: arrays, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to simplify some codes and wanted to loop through an array, from which the scope names will be taken from:

```
<template>
  <q-btn-toggle v-model="encryptionType" spread class="q-mt-lg" no-caps unelevated :toggle-color="toggleColor" :toggle-text-color="toggleTextColor" :color="color" :text-color="textColor" @update:model-value="checkButtonToggle" :options="options">
    <div v-if="options.length > 1">
      <div v-for="type in options" :key="type.value">
        <template #[type.value]> <!-- seems like this part isnt working correctly -->
          <q-icon v-if="props[type.value] && encryptionType === type.value" name="check_circle" color="white" class="q-ml-sm" />
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-btn-toggle>
</template>
```

Then the options is like this:

```js
options: [
  { label: 'rsa', value: 'rsa', attrs: { class: 'text-weight-bold font-size-18' }, slot: 'rsa' }
  { label: 'des', value: 'des', attrs: { class: 'text-weight-bold font-size-18' }, slot: 'des' }
  { label: 'aes', value: 'aes', attrs: { class: 'text-weight-bold font-size-18' }, slot: 'aes' }
]
```

However I am getting this error message:

```
Codegen node is missing for element/if/for node. Apply appropriate transforms first.
```

If I change how I use scoped slots to this, then there's no error, but  isnt rendered as well.

```
      <div v-for="type of options" :key="type.value">
        <template :v-slot="type.value">
          <q-icon v-if="props[type.value] && encryptionType === type.value" name="check_circle" color="white" class="q-ml-sm" />
        </template>
      </div>
```

Want a cleaner way to do it since doing this is just plain too repetitive:

```
<template #des>
  <q-icon  v-if="props.des && encryptionType === 'des'" name="check_circle" color="white" class="q-ml-sm" />
</template>

<template #aes>
  <q-icon  v-if="props.aes && encryptionType === 'aes'" name="check_circle" color="white" class="q-ml-sm" />
</template>

<template #rsa>
  <q-icon v-if="props.rsa && encryptionType === 'rsa'" name="check_circle" color="white" class="q-ml-sm" />
</template>
```

Help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'type in options' instead of 'type of options'?

Comment: I tried ```type in options``` and also got the same results. I updated my code above to use ```in``` instead of ```of```. THank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the slots wrong. The problem is easily recreated.
You insert this into the default slot of `q-btn-toggle`:

```
<div v-if="options.length > 1">
```

And then inside the default slot you try to insert into name slots which don't exists. Thus `node is missing.`

To fix you just change your DIVs to `<template>`. Unfortunately 2 `<template>`s with `v-if` and `v-for` didn't work for me, but it's easily fixed with a ternar expression:

[The SFC playground is here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

```
  <q-btn-toggle v-model="encryptionType" spread class="q-mt-lg" no-caps unelevated :toggle-color="toggleColor" :toggle-text-color="toggleTextColor" :color="color" :text-color="textColor" @update:model-value="checkButtonToggle" :options="options">
      <template v-for="type in options.length > 1 ? options : []" :key="type.value" #[type.value]>
          <q-icon v-if="props[type.value] && encryptionType === type.value" name="check_circle" color="white" class="q-ml-sm" />
      </template>
  </q-btn-toggle>
```

Recreation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This gave me an idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @alexander-nenashev, I got an idea on how to fix it. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
  <q-btn-toggle v-model="encryptionType" spread class="q-mt-lg" no-caps unelevated :toggle-color="toggleColor"
    :toggle-text-color="toggleTextColor" :color="color" :text-color="textColor" @update:model-value="checkButtonToggle"
    :options="options">
    <template v-for="type in options" #[type.value]>
      <q-icon v-if="props[type.value] && encryptionType === type.value" name="check_circle" color="white"
        class="q-ml-sm" />
    </template>
  </q-btn-toggle>
```

Comment: you forgot your v-if

Comment: You shouldn't post code-only answers, please add an explanation how it solves the issue of the question.